# Using hunspell in C

Tags: hunspell

I would like to use hunspell in my C program. I'm working in a Unix environment (shell) and it has already hunspell built in.
I know I can use by typing
hunspell filename
at the command line, but I wanna know how to use it inside my program. Ultimately I want to store every dictionary word but first I just want to know how to import it into my program.
Like is there #include  type of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a hunspell API you can use through `#include <hunspell/hunspell.h>` The API details can be found at the [hunspell documentation page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hunspell/files/Hunspell/Documentation/) (hunspell3.pdf). Examples are a bit scarce, but [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Spell-Checking-with-Hunspell) or [this](http://snipplr.com/view/24205/) should get you started.

Comment: Great thanks. Would you happen to know how to compile it tho? I tried
`gcc -lhunspell test.c` but it's giving me errors

Comment: What sort of errors? `gcc test.c -lhunspell` might do the trick, though.

Comment: oh my, sorry about that, it should be `<hunspell/hunspell.h>`.

Comment: Same error :(
error: hunspell/hunspell.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Do you actually have the dev files? Try `find`-ing hunspell to see if you have the h and the so files.. I don't know about your system, but in Debian and derivatives you'd need to install a hunspell-dev package if you're missing the files.